# Get online users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have one user for login to demo of my script.
I want get how many people online now.
I use `laravel 5.2`
What am I do?

Comment: if you are using Redis as a Session Driver, [here is your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305740/laravel-all-sessions-ids-with-redis-driver/55545047#55545047)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep sessions in a DB and use `last_activity` column to determine how many users are currently online.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#introduction

Comment: I want get online users with one username.

Comment: If you want to get usernames, you should do some stuff to make Laravel add user ID to a session. Please look at this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-store-users-id-in-session-table-laravel-5/replies/86313

Answer (score 1):

There is a laravel plugin to achieve this.
here's the link :https://github.com/thomastkim/laravel-online-users

Comment: I use activity for other plugin

Comment: sorry, I didn't get that

Comment: probably `Activity` model..?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below package in order to get online users or determine if a user is online or not.

https://github.com/shetabit/visitor

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)