# How to sorting by current login user first in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Below code is to divide list view by permission in the Job table.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user_name = Auth::user()->name;

    $jobs = Job::orderBy('created_at', 'desc') //@default
    ->where('is_trash', '==', 0)
    ->paginate(15);

    if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Admin')){   //check by permission 
    $jobs = Job::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('user_name', '=', $user_name)
    ->where('is_trash', '==', 0)
    ->orderby('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);
    }

    return view('jobs.index')
        ->with('jobs', $jobs);
}
```

For example, current login user name is C and there has A, B, D users.
Then I wish to show list as

```
------------------------------
C
A
B
D
------------------------------
```

How do I sort the currently logged in users first in the list?
Thank you in advance.:)

Comment: Do you store somehow whether an user is logged in or not?

Comment: @Ivanka, typically if the op hasn't changed the settings it'd store within the `storage/framework/sessions.`

Comment: @Magnetic, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811097/get-online-users-in-laravel would have the relevant info of how to do this and then you just run an orderBy

Answer (score 2):

To place a row above all other rows and then order the remaining rows in ascending / descending order you need to do something like this `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field = value ASC`

So for your query something like this should work

```
$user_name = Auth::user()->name;

$jobs = Job::orderByRaw("user_name = ':name' ASC", ['name' => $user_name])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('is_trash', '==', 0)
    ->paginate(15);
```

I'm not entirely sure which query you wish to order and by which field but this example should give you enough to adapt on. It is untested but if `:name` isn't working as per the example try wrapping the query in `\DB::raw()` to add the binding `$user_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) for that. Just tested, works perfectly:

```
list($user, $collection) = $collection->partition(function($user) {
    return $user->id === auth()->id();
});
$collection = $user->merge($collection);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried with you code, but I couldn't use link() in Laravel.  'ErrorException
Method links does not exist.' 
 what can I do to use?:)

Comment: @Magnetic [create a `Paginator` instance manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Comment: thanks but I don't understant... I trying with below code. could you check where have error? :) 
'$jobs = Auth::user();
        
        $collection = Job::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('is_trash', '==', 0)
        ->get();

        list($jobs, $collection) = $collection->partition(function($jobs) {
            return $jobs->id === auth()->id();
        });
        $collection = $jobs->merge($collection);

        return view('jobs.index')
            ->with('jobs', $jobs);'