# Laravel all sessions IDs with Redis driver

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.4

In my application I want to allow for some user, to be able to sign out all other users except him/her. I have done this functionality, well, when the Session driver was set to file, but now I'm using redis as session driver and I could not able to find any way to list up all current sessions like I have done when it was file driver.

**The question is**:  How to list up all sessions IDs when using redis as a session driver?

The following is the code that I have used when session driver was file:

```
public function signoutAllUsers(Request $request,$sesId=null){
        //dd(session());
        if ($sesId == session()->getId()){
            $dir = storage_path().'/framework/sessions';
            $files = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($files as $file){
                if ($file == session()->getId() || strpos($file,'.') !== false){
                    //echo "ggg";
                    continue;
                }
                try{
                    unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
                }
                catch(\Exception $e){
                    return $e;
                }                

            }
            $request->session()->flash('status','success');
            $request->session()->flash('msg',__('All users have been signed out successfully'));
            return redirect('/method/create');

        }
        else{
            return redirect('/method/create');
        }

    }
```

## Update

I have found a limited solution that depends on `Redis` facade method `command`:

`Redis::command('keys',['*'])`

However, it returns output looks like:

`array:4 [▼
  0 => "laravel:cav17Job1_7l46wAdE2--__"
  1 => "laravel:cav17Job1_7l46wAdE2--_"
  2 => "laravel:WwerTYmw2VNAfR5nKj3OOGBp2hKytSBK4MWMJ2P9"
  3 => "laravel:12tyuwzoFhXPM4f6w4yRPxrYywPon4W41neq6gu"
]`
 
The above output contains both sessions ids and other cache entries, in my application I am using Redis for cache too.

The question becomes, How could I give sessions stored in redis, different key other than `laravel` which is the cache key?

Comment: Thank you for your `limited solution`. It clarifies the situation a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your `session` and `cache` separate.

In the file `\config\database.php`

You can set **many** `redis` connections, by default there is a `"default"` but you can add more to it

let's say you created `'session-connection'` and `'cache-connection'`

now you need to make use of it

go to file 'config\session.php'

and set it to `'connection' => 'session-connection',`

then go to file `config\cache.php`

and set it to

```
    'redis' => [
        'driver'     => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache-connection',
    ],
```

and now you can get your redis session records.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
\Log::debug( Redis::connection('session-connection')->keys('*') );
```

Comment: Please, let me know if you need a hint of how to keep your `queue-redis-connection` separate and if you want to use a separate Redis DataBases for your connections...

Comment: It is great solution. There is no any problem if you would like to add more related hints.