# How do I get all Laravel user sessions?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I use Redis to store sessions, but how do I get **all** of the user's sessions? This is easy to do when using mysql, but how can I do it when using Redis?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to retrieve all the data in the session, you may use the all method:

```
$data = $request->session()->all();
```

Check Laravel [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#retrieving-data)

Comment: returns only the current user session, and I need all sessions(

Comment: Which driver are using ?

Comment: 'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis')

Comment: need to use predis?

Comment: could you pls add your .env file and config/session.php ?

Comment: # .env
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

# config/session.php is default

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305740/laravel-all-sessions-ids-with-redis-driver

Comment: Thank you, but this outputs all sessions to all users. I need to get sessions only for a specific user

Answer (score 0):

To get all sessions you can do:

```php
$all_sessions = $request->session()->all();
```

To get the sessions associated to the currently authenticated user:

```php
$user_sessions = \DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: The question specifically mentioned Redis twice as the designated session driver. Your answer is only applicable to those using the database session driver.